# Appium Inspector on Windows with real devices

Tags: android, windows, automated-tests, appium

Does Appium Inspector work on Windows with real Android devices or only with emulators?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that it works with a real device if I set the "Device Name" (and "Application Path") in Android Settings in Appium app and then launch Inspektor and click "Refresh" button. After few seconds app launches on my connected android phone and I can see it in Inspector. Nevertheless I think that uiautomatorviewer works better on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it works but you have to use uiautomator viewer if you are in Windows or if you are using mac just install android file transfer to make the real device connected to mac.

Comment: Uiautomatorviewer is a different tool.

Comment: I know that but the problem is that you say inspector of appium in windows which is not possible cause it works only in mac

Answer (score 0):

It works.

Use `adb devices` to make sure your real devices is connected. If not, check USB Debugging mode (In Developer options) is enabled or not.

Answer (score 0):

I am working with Appium android for 2 years
it works well with android real devices
make sure that you have enabled debugging under the developer option.